# Call a block method on an iterator: each.magic.collect { ... }

Tags: ruby, iterator

I have a class with a custom each-method:

```
class CurseArray < Array
    def each_safe
        each do |element|
            unless element =~ /bad/
                yield element
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

And want to call different block methods, like "collect" or "inject" on those iterated elements. For example:

```
curse_array.each_safe.magic.collect {|element| "#{element} is a nice sentence."}
```

I know there is a specific function (which I called "magic" here) to do this, but I've forgotten. Please help! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a method yields you will need to pass it a block. There is no way define a block that automatically passes itself.

Closest I can get to your spec is this:

```
def magic(meth)
  to_enum(meth)
end

def test
  yield 1 
  yield 2
end

magic(:test).to_a
# returns: [1,2]
```

The cleanest way of implementing your request is probably:

```
class MyArray < Array 
  def each_safe 
    return to_enum :each_safe unless block_given? 
    each{|item| yield item unless item =~ /bad/}
  end 
end

a = MyArray.new 
a << "good"; a << "bad" 
a.each_safe.to_a
# returns ["good"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote your `each_safe` method, the easiest would be

```
curse_array.each_safe { |element| do_something_with(element) }
```

**Edit:**  Oh, your each_safe method isn't correct, either. It has to be "each do", not "each.do"

**Edit 2:** If you really want to be able to do things like "`each_safe.map`", while at the same time also being able to do "`each_safe { ... }`" you could write your method like this:

```
require 'enumerator'

class CurseArray < Array
  BLACKLIST = /bad/
  def each_safe
    arr = []
    each do |element|
      unless element =~ BLACKLIST
        if block_given?
          yield element
        else
          arr << element
        end
      end
    end

    unless block_given?
      return Enumerator.new(arr)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I meant to use =~ for regexp matching.

The way you describe is how I do it now, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: @blinry your use of `=~` and a `Regexp` there is correct since you'll probably want to put more words in the blacklist. @dominikh's approach to letting `each_safe` work with or without a block is a good one.

Comment: It's a bad idea to build the answers and then return an enumerator. THe whole idea of Enumerators is to have lazy evaluation! What if the array is modified after `each_safe` being called but before using the enumerator? What if it's a long text and we only need `first(3)`? Check Sam's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The selected solution uses the common idiom `to_enum :method_name unless block_given?` which it's ok, but there are alternatives:

1. Leave your "unfriendly" yielder method untouched, use `enum_for` when calling it.
2. Use a lazy `Enumerator`.
3. Use lazy arrays (needs [Ruby 2.0](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4890) or gem [enumerable-lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy)).

Here's a demo code:

```
class CurseArray < Array
  def each_safe
    each do |element|
      unless element =~ /bad/
        yield element
      end
    end
  end 

  def each_safe2
    Enumerator.new do |enum|
      each do |element|
        unless element =~ /bad/
          enum.yield element
        end
      end
    end
  end 

  def each_safe3
    lazy.map do |element|
      unless element =~ /bad/
        element
      end
    end.reject(&:nil?)
  end 
end

xs = CurseArray.new(["good1", "bad1", "good2"])
xs.enum_for(:each_safe).select { |x| x.length > 1 }
xs.each_safe2.select { |x| x.length > 1 }
xs.each_safe3.select { |x| x.length > 1 }.to_a
```